# Save clientEvents from FullCalendar in MySQL /w PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm using `FullCalendar` and I want to save all `events` on `form.submit()` in MySQL database in a `blob` field.
I thought I could convert it to JSON and then set it to a `hidden` input, then save it with `PHP`. But I get the JSON error for `Converting circular structure to JSON`.

Here is my code and the output.

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
    var events = $('#calendar-cabinet').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');

    console.log(events);
});
```

[image: result from console.log(events)]

Answer (score 1):

Is the input field that contains json also looped by the script that puts json in the input?

Your data already shows javascript / json objects, so you should be able to post the events as array in an object, to have the events array available in $_POST['events'].

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
    var events = $('#calendar-cabinet').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
    var url = 'your_url';
    var data = {events:events};

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to convert it to a data type suitable to set it in the input.

Comment: As I see in the console log, each event is a javascript (therefor already json) object. You should be able to send these in a simple jquery post request.